# Vue 2 cli console off in release build?

Tags: vue.js

I have small vue2 cli project that is really difficult to configure. I don't know why all the examples that I found gives build error

I have now vue.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
    //publicPath: '/xxx',
    configureWebpack: {
        devtool: 'source-map'

    }
}
```

what i need to do to make console off in release build?

Comment: What build errors you've got?

Comment: this field is too short for the log but its here [link]https://pastebin.com/7WXHaahU and it comes always if i add something to vue.config.js I also have standard babel.config.js that says ``` module.exports = { presets: [ '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset' ] } ``` (wtf is with this code markup here!!?!?!?)